# multiple :not() with dynamic element attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is demo http://jsfiddle.net/NbzaE/3/

What i'm trying to do:

Disable animation if **.list-item**'s attribute **data-attr** is **true**

Here is the working example:

```
$('.list-item > a:not(.active)').hover(function(){
        $(this).clearQueue().stop().animate({
            marginLeft: 40
        }, 250);
    }, function(){
        $('.list-item:not([data-attr="true"]) > a:not(.active)').clearQueue().stop().animate({
            marginLeft: 0
        }, 250);
 });
```

But i'm not sure that it's proper. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see any problem in your code. You can use it.

Comment: What do you mean by "unbind animation"? Animations are not bound.

Comment: like @sdespont said, your code works.  As a sidenote, you might consider `paddingLeft` over `marginLeft` because if you're mouse is in that indented space on the left it traps the animation in a mouseover/mouseout loop.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?
Hover was depricated in 1.9, and before I realized this, I used it, and was met with strange results - it acted sort of like toggle did, but not reliably.

Answer (score 0):

You really should use mouseenter, mouseleave events, based on: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#hover-pseudo-event and in your fiddle you have a part setting the data for a parent element on click that could be simpler:

```
$('li.list-item').on('mouseenter', '>a:not(.active)', function () {
    $(this).clearQueue().stop().animate({
        marginLeft: 40
    }, 250);
});
$('li.list-item').on('mouseleave', '>a:not(.active)', function () {
    $(this).clearQueue().stop().animate({
        marginLeft: 0
    }, 250);
});

$('.list-item[data-toggle="collapse"] ').on('click', '>a', function () {
    $(this).parent().data('attr', !$(this).parent().data('attr'));
});
```

EDIT1: Side note, you can also capture that second event on the element not on the link saving the `.parent()` traversal as in:

```
$('.list-item[data-toggle="collapse"] ').click( function () {
    $(this).data('attr', !$(this).data('attr'));
});
```

AND IF you are dynamically creating those li elements attach to the ul:

```
$('ul').on('click', '.list-item[data-toggle="collapse"] ', function () {
    alert($(this).data('attr'));
    $(this).data('attr', !$(this).data('attr'));
});
```

Comment: this code `$('.list-item[data-toggle="collapse"] ').on('click', '>a', function () {
    $(this).parent().data('attr', !$(this).parent().data('attr'));
});` and two other variations are not working for me. Your script doesnt toggle data-attr true/false

Comment: Also your scripts working fine on hover, but animation is not stopping when `.list-item` has `data-attr="true"`